# How to write this sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with the following structure

```
cod_turn (PrimaryKey)
taken    (bit)
time     (datetime)
```

and several other fields which are irrelevant to the problem. I cant alter the table structure because the app was made by someone else.

given a numeric variable parameter, which we will assume to be "3" for this example, and a time, I need to create a query which looking from that time on, it looks the first 3 consecutive records which are not marked as "taken". I cant figure out how to make the query in pure sql, if possible.

PS: I accepted the answer because it was correct, but I made a bad description of the problem. I will open another question later. Feeling stupid after seeing the size of the answers =)

Comment: what is your criterion for "consecutive records" ? time ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM table WHERE taken = 0 AND time>=@Time ORDER BY time
```

Where @Time is whatever time you pass in.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming current versions of SQL Server and assuming you've named you "numeric variable parameter" as `@top int`. Note:the parenthesis around `@top` *are required* when using a parameter-ized TOP

```
SELECT TOP (@top) 
   cod_turn,
   taken ,
   time
FROM yourtable 
 WHERE Taken = 0 AND time>=@Time 
ORDER BY time     DESC
```

You can also do

```
with cte as 
(
    SELECT 
       ROW_NUMBER() over (order by time desc) rn
       cod_turn,
       taken ,
       time
    FROM yourtable 
     WHERE Taken = 0 AND time>=@Time 
)
SELECT 
cod_turn,
       taken ,
       time
FROM CTE
WHERE rn <= @top
    ORDER BY time     DESC
```

Comment: Yeah they added that in 2005. Its a real PIA in SQL 2000

Comment: Just when parametrising TOP you have to use braces: TOP (@top), not the same as with constant value: TOP 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 3 
* 
FROM 
   table 
WHERE 
   time >= @inserted_time 
   AND taken = 0 
ORDER BY 
   cod_turn ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select MT.*
from 
(
    select cod_turn, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cod_turn) [RowNumber] -- or by time
    from myTable
    where taken = 0
    and time >= @myTime
) T
inner join myTable MT on MT.cod_turn = T.cod_turn
where T.RowNumber < @myNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 3 * from theTable where taken = 0 and time > theTime orderby time
```