# How to make this sql query

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 SQL Server tables with the following structure

```
Turns-time

cod_turn (PrimaryKey) 
time     (datetime)

Taken turns

cod_taken_turn (Primary Key)
cod_turn
...
```

and several other fields which are irrelevant to the problem. I cant alter the table structures because the app was made by someone else.

given a numeric variable parameter, which we will assume to be "3" for this example, and a given time, I need to create a query which looking from that time on, it looks the first 3 consecutive records by time which are not marked as "taken". For example:

For example, for these turns, starting by the time of "8:00" chosen by the user

```
 8:00 (not taken)
 9:00 (not taken)
10:00 (taken)
11:00 (not taken)
12:00 (not taken)
13:00 (not taken)
14:00 (taken)
```

The query it would have to list

```
11:00
12:00
13:00
```

I cant figure out how to make the query in pure sql, if possible.

Comment: Which variant of SQL are you using? Oracle, DB2 or something else?

Comment: How is a time marked as taken? Because a corresponding record exists in `Taken turns`?

Comment: Also, what is the column that is used to check if the turn has been taken?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write this sql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852534/how-to-write-this-sql-query)

Comment: @ypercube - This is a different question. The OP admits in that one they made a bit of a hash of explaining it properly. All the answers there don't do the consecutive requirement from a quick glance.

Comment: Yes Martin Smith, when a record exists in Taken turns it's because it is "taken". That's the only way we have to know if it's taken

Comment: That question you linked as possible duplicate, it was a badly attempt to explain this problem by me yesterday. I didnt erase it because it described another problem and some people took the time to answer it

Comment: @All: I agree, it was not an exact duplicate. Perhaps, you could have provided a link to it, explaining that it was not exactly what you wanted, as you did in this comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH Base AS (
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS(
               SELECT * 
               FROM Taken_turns taken 
               WHERE taken.cod_turn = turns.cod_turn) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS taken
FROM   [Turns-time] turns)
, RecursiveCTE As (
SELECT TOP 1 cod_turn, [time], taken AS run, 0 AS grp
FROM  Base 
WHERE [time] >= @start_time
ORDER BY [time]
UNION   ALL
SELECT  R.cod_turn, R.[time], R.run, R.grp
FROM    (
        SELECT  T.*,
                CASE WHEN T.taken = 0 THEN 0 ELSE run+1 END AS run,
                CASE WHEN T.taken = 0 THEN grp + 1 ELSE grp END AS grp,
                rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.[time])
        FROM    Base T
        JOIN    RecursiveCTE R
                ON  R.[time] < T.[time]
        ) R
WHERE   R.rn = 1 AND run < @run_length
),  T AS(
SELECT *, 
        MAX(grp) OVER () AS FinalGroup,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) AS group_size
FROM RecursiveCTE
)
SELECT cod_turn,time
FROM T 
WHERE grp=FinalGroup AND group_size=@run_length
```

Comment: @Pablo - I've made a slight amend to it so it will ensure that the final group is of the required size (for the case that you have no matching sequence in the data)

Answer (score 3):

with a cursor

```
declare @GivenTime datetime,
        @GivenSequence int;

select  @GivenTime = cast('08:00' as datetime),
        @GivenSequence = 3;

declare @sequence int,
        @code_turn int, 
        @time datetime,
        @taked int,
        @firstTimeInSequence datetime;

set @sequence = 0;

declare turnCursor cursor FAST_FORWARD for 
                        select turn.cod_turn, turn.[time], taken.cod_taken_turn
                        from [Turns-time] as turn
                        left join [Taken turns] as taken on turn.cod_turn = taken.cod_turn
                        where turn.[time]  >= @GivenTime
                        order by turn.[time] asc;

open turnCursor;
fetch next from turnCursor into @code_turn, @time, @taked;

while @@fetch_status = 0 AND @sequence < @GivenSequence
begin
    if @taked IS NULL
        select  @firstTimeInSequence = coalesce(@firstTimeInSequence, @time)
                ,@sequence = @sequence + 1;
    else
        select  @sequence = 0,
                @firstTimeInSequence = null;

    fetch next from turnCursor into @code_turn, @time, @taked;
end

close turnCursor;
deallocate turnCursor;

if @sequence = @GivenSequence
    select top (@GivenSequence) * from [Turns-time] where [time] >= @firstTimeInSequence
    order by [time] asc
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is not a simple way to achieve this.

But probably there are many complex ways :). This is an approach that should work in Transact-SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE #CONSECUTIVE_TURNS (id int identity, time datetime, consecutive int)

INSERT INTO #CONSECUTIVE_TURNS (time, consecutive, 0)
      SELECT cod_turn
           , time
           , 0
        FROM Turns-time
    ORDER BY time

DECLARE @i int
        @n int
SET @i = 0
SET @n = 3  -- Number of consecutive not taken records

while (@i < @n) begin
    UPDATE #CONSECUTIVE_TURNS
       SET consecutive = consecutive + 1
     WHERE not exists (SELECT 1
                         FROM Taken-turns
                        WHERE id = cod_turn + @i
                      )

    SET @i = @i + 1
end

DECLARE @firstElement int

SELECT @firstElement = min(id)
  FROM #CONSECUTIVE_TURNS
 WHERE consecutive >= @n

SELECT *
  FROM #CONSECUTIVE_TURNS
 WHERE id between @firstElement 
              and @firstElement + @n - 1
```

This is untested but I think it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Pure SQL

```
SELECT TOP 3 time FROM [turns-time] WHERE time >= (

  -- get first result of the 3 consecutive results
  SELECT TOP 1 time AS first_result
  FROM [turns-time] tt

  -- start from given time, which is 8:00 in this case
  WHERE time >= '08:00'

  -- turn is not taken
  AND cod_turn NOT IN (SELECT cod_turn FROM taken_turns)

  -- 3 consecutive turns from current turn are not taken
  AND (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
      (
        SELECT TOP 3 cod_turn AS selected_turn FROM [turns-time] tt2 WHERE tt2.time >= tt.time
        GROUP BY cod_turn ORDER BY tt2.time
      ) AS temp
    WHERE selected_turn NOT IN (SELECT cod_turn FROM taken_turns)) = 3
) ORDER BY time
```

Note: I tested it on Postgresql (with some code modification), but not MS SQL Server. I'm not sure about performance compared to T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Another set-based solution (tested):

```
DECLARE @Results TABLE
(
     cod_turn   INT NOT NULL
    ,[status]   TINYINT NOT NULL
    ,RowNumber  INT PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT  @Results (cod_turn, [status], RowNumber)
SELECT   a.cod_turn
        ,CASE WHEN b.cod_turn IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [status] --1=(not taken), 0=(taken)
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.[time]) AS RowNumber
FROM    [Turns-time] a
LEFT JOIN [Taken_turns] b ON a.cod_turn = b.cod_turn 
WHERE   a.[time] >= @Start;

--SELECT * FROM @Results r ORDER BY r.RowNumber;

SELECT  *
FROM
(
SELECT  TOP(1) ca.LastRowNumber
FROM    @Results a
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT SUM(c.status) CountNotTaken, MAX(c.RowNumber) LastRowNumber
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  TOP(@Len)
                b.RowNumber, b.[status]
        FROM    @Results b
        WHERE   b.RowNumber <= a.RowNumber 
        ORDER BY b.RowNumber DESC
    ) c
) ca
WHERE   ca.CountNotTaken = @Len
ORDER BY a.RowNumber ASC
) x INNER JOIN @Results y ON x.LastRowNumber - @Len + 1 <= y.RowNumber AND y.RowNumber <= x.LastRowNumber;
```